# How normalize data-input after a layers.concatenate() in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, tensorflow2.0

I have a CNN with a concatenate-layer at the beginning of Dense network. I use the layer.concatenate() to merge the features retrieved by CNN and my hand-crafted features. Now, this 2 data arrays, have 2 different scale (because the first are values calculated by the CNN and the other are features calculated by me). So I would a way to normalize this 2 type of data in a common scale for simplify the job. This is my CNN:

```
emb = Embedding()(image_input)
conv = Conv1D(64, 2, activation = 'relu', strides = 1, padding = 'same')(emb)
conv = MaxPooling1D()(conv1)
first_part_output = Flatten()(conV)

merged_model = layers.concatenate([first_part_output, other_data_input])
```

Here i would do the normalization:

```
normal = *here i would do the normalization*

primoDense = Dense(256, activation = 'relu')(normal)
drop = Dropout(0.45)(primoDense)
predictions = Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(drop)
```

**[first_part_output, other_data_input]** is my new merged-array.
**first_part_output** are CNN featues.
**other_data_input** are my hand-crafted features.

Comment: What kind of normalization do you need? Is it just standardizing data? If not, can you write down that as an equation?

Comment: Maybe you know _exactly_ what you're doing, but a few questions/comments come to my mind. Is it _that_ clear to you that they are on different scales? The picture inputs are supposed to be scaled between 0 and 1 before going into the NN, and your custom features too. Also, logically, I'd normalize before concatenation, doing it after doesn't make sense to me. But then, like I said, maybe you're an expert and know things that I don't. Is there a reason why you're using a 1 dimensional convolutional layer on pictures?